# Как работает кеширование DNS в Windows 7?

Tags: dns

Все ли просмотренные сайты из любого браузера попадают в кеш DNS? Как долго хранится кеш, есть ли у него лимит на количество кешированных IP адресов? Может ли получение данных таким образом служит историей посещенных веб-сайтов?

Проверял кеш DNS [так](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1809/%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-powershell). В результатах не было сайта, который смотрел вчера. После посещения этого сайта проверил опять кеш DNS, он там появился. Отсюда и вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, попадают все.
2. Каждая запись имеет "Срок жизни" ("Время жизни"). Данное значение определяет время в секундах, которое запись будет находиться в кэше. А значит эта запись будет в `ipconfig /displaydns`. Записи из файла `hosts` находятся в ней постоянно с максимальным временем жизни.
3. Размер таблицы содержится в следующих директивах реестра: `CacheHashTableBucketSize` и `CacheHashTableSize`
4. Таким образом можно собирать некоторую статистику, но все будет очень зависеть и от политики системы и от переменных реестра и от времени жизни ДНС записей. Т.е. по сути весьма и весьма субъективная оценка истории посещений. Разве что собирать ее очень и очень часто (1-5 секунд, т.к. при входе на тот же `mail.ru` в кеш добавляются записи и со временем жизни в 4с). Более того, полагаю, что ДНС-кэш очищается при перезагрузке компьютера.